# Passing Objects to Zend Soap Server

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap

I'm trying to implement a Soap server and I'm currently trying to see if the Soap server in Zend Framework (1) will do what I need. I am interested in trying to take advantage of it's auto-discovery to create the WSDL so I don't constantly have to maintain one separately any time changes are made to the functions or data types.

I set up a basic server and I was able to get auto-discovery to seemingly do what I want, and played with the class map in the client and was able to get it to properly populate a model from the returned data for a couple of complex data types. However, I can't seem to figure out how to pass the client an object and have it show up properly on the far end.

When I initially just passed in an array of values (nested/associated), the client produced the desired result in the 'output' types/models/objects. But when I'm trying to pass the object into the client code, it shows up on the server as an array of values (and not an associative one - the keys are dropped. On one other test, I tried nesting objects, the second object showed up as stdClass but at least had the expected key/values, but the outer one is always a sequential array)

It appears that the autoDiscover is at least pretending it's ready to do what I want, but I don't know how to get the data from the object sent into the client to show up properly at the server.

Data received by server code:

```
array (
  0 => 4,
  1 => 12,
  2 => 7,
  3 => 98.6,
  4 => 9.18,
  5 => 3.1415,
  6 => 'foobar',
  7 => 'change',
  8 => 'bumblebee',
)
```

Input class:

```
class InputType {
    /**
     * @var integer $intOne
     */
    public $intOne;
    /**
     * @var integer $intTwo
     */
    public $intTwo;
    /**
     * @var integer $intThree
     */
    public $intThree;
    /**
     * @var float $floatOne
     */
    public $floatOne;
    /**
     * @var float $floatTwo
     */
    public $floatTwo;
    /**
     * @var float $floatThree
     */
    public $floatThree;
    /**
     * @var string $stringOne
     */
    public $stringOne;
    /**
     * @var string $stringOne
     */
    public $stringTwo;
    /**
     * @var string $stringThree
     */
    public $stringThree;
}
```

Sample Complex object (output parent layer)

```
require_once('SOAP/Types/TestClassType.php');
class TestType {
    /**
     * @var integer $intVar
     */
    public $intVar;
    /**
     * @var float $floatVar
     */
    public $floatVar;
    /**
     * @var string $stringVar
     */
    public $stringVar;
    /**
     * @var array $arrayVar
     */
    public $arrayVar;
    /**
     * @var TestClassType $classVar
     */
    public $classVar;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->classVar = new TestClassType();
    }
}
```

Test Class model (child of output)

```
class TestClassType {
    /**
     * @var integer $testInt
     */
    public $testInt;
    /**
     * @var float $testFloat
     */
    public $testFloat;
    /**
     * @var string $testString
     */
    public $testString;
}
```

Server code (functions):

```
require_once('SOAP/Types/InputType.php');
require_once('SOAP/Types/TestType.php');
require_once('SOAP/Types/TestClassType.php');

class Soap_Server {
    /**
     * get a complex type
     *
     * @param InputType $inp
     * @return TestType
     */
    public function get_test_type($inp) {
        error_log("Input: " . var_export($inp,1));
        $tt = new TestType();
        $tt->intVar    = $inp->intOne;
        $tt->floatVar  = $inp->floatOne;
        $tt->stringVar = $inp->stringOne;
        $tt->arrayVar  = array(
            'int' => $inp->intThree,
            'float' => $inp->floatThree,
            'string' => $inp->stringThree
        );
        $tt->classVar->testInt    = $inp->intTwo;
        $tt->classVar->testFloat  = $inp->floatTwo;
        $tt->classVar->testString = $inp->stringTwo;
        return $tt;
    }
}
```

Server request handler (run on apache2):

```
require_once('SOAP/Types/InputType.php');
require_once('SOAP/Types/TestType.php');
require_once('SOAP/Types/TestClassType.php');
require_once('SOAP/Server.php');


if(isset($_GET['wsdl'])) {
    //return the WSDL
    handleWSDL();
} else {
    //handle SOAP request
    handleSOAP();
}
exit();

function handleWSDL() {
    require_once('Zend/Soap/AutoDiscover.php');
    $autodiscover = new Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover();
    $autodiscover->setClass('Soap_Server');
    ob_clean();
    ob_start();
    $autodiscover->handle();
}
function handleSOAP() {
    $wsdl = "http://localhost/soap/zendserver.php?wsdl";
    require_once('Zend/Soap/Server.php');
    $server = new Zend_Soap_Server($wsdl);
    $server->setClass('Soap_Server');
    $server->setClassmap(
        array(
            'InputType'     => 'InputType',
            'TestType'      => 'TestType',
            'TestClassType' => 'TestClassType'
        )
    );
    $server->handle();
}
```

testing Client code:

```
require_once('SOAP/Types/InputType.php');
require_once('SOAP/Types/TestType.php');
require_once('SOAP/Types/TestClassType.php');
require_once('Zend/Soap/Client.php');

$wsdl = "http://localhost/soap/zendserver.php?wsdl";
$client = new Zend_Soap_Client($wsdl, array('cache_wsdl' => false ));

$client->setClassmap(
    array(
        'InputType'     => 'InputType',
        'TestType'      => 'TestType',
        'TestClassType' => 'TestClassType'
    )
);

$client->setWsdlCache(false);

$bar = new InputType();
$bar->intOne = 4;
$bar->floatOne = 98.6;
$bar->stringOne = "foobar";
$bar->intTwo = 12;
$bar->floatTwo = 9.18;
$bar->stringTwo = "change";
$bar->intThree = 7;
$bar->floatThree = 3.1415;
$bar->stringThree = "bumblebee";

$result = $client->get_test_type($bar);
```

autoDiscover WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://localhost/soap/zendserver.php" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="Soap_Server" targetNamespace="http://localhost/soap/zendserver.php">
  <types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://localhost/soap/zendserver.php">
      <xsd:complexType name="InputType">
        <xsd:all>
          <xsd:element name="intOne" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element name="intTwo" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element name="intThree" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element name="floatOne" type="xsd:float" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element name="floatTwo" type="xsd:float" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element name="floatThree" type="xsd:float" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element name="stringOne" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element name="stringTwo" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element name="stringThree" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        </xsd:all>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:complexType name="TestClassType">
        <xsd:all>
          <xsd:element name="testInt" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element name="testFloat" type="xsd:float" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element name="testString" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
        </xsd:all>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:complexType name="TestType">
        <xsd:all>
          <xsd:element name="intVar" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element name="floatVar" type="xsd:float" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element name="stringVar" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element name="arrayVar" type="soap-enc:Array" nillable="true"/>
          <xsd:element name="classVar" type="tns:TestClassType" nillable="true"/>
        </xsd:all>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
  <portType name="Soap_ServerPort">
    <operation name="get_test_type">
      <documentation>get a complex type</documentation>
      <input message="tns:get_test_typeIn"/>
      <output message="tns:get_test_typeOut"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="Soap_ServerBinding" type="tns:Soap_ServerPort">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="get_test_type">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://localhost/soap/zendserver.php#get_test_type"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://www.localhost.com/soap/zendserver.php"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://localhost/soap/zendserver.php"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="Soap_ServerService">
    <port name="Soap_ServerPort" binding="tns:Soap_ServerBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost/soap/zendserver.php"/>
    </port>
  </service>
  <message name="get_test_typeIn">
    <part name="inp" type="tns:InputType"/>
  </message>
  <message name="get_test_typeOut">
    <part name="return" type="tns:TestType"/>
  </message>
</definitions>
```

Comment: Further testing notes:
I tried running a similar test inside of a zend-framework test site sandbox and was able to get the object(s) to pass in with no problem. I also ran a client using the uri instead of wsdl parameter and that also works. I have no idea why it's not working with wsdl outside of the framework.